# Backbonejs append 2 views to parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

i don't know how to explain my problem properly...

I want do append always two views to one div container without using this.setElement().

Parent View:

```
var app = app || {};

app.WidgetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('.widgets'),

initialize: function(options) {
    self = this;
    this.collection = options.collection;
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.renderViews(item)

    }, this);
},

renderViews: function(item) {
    this.View = new app.WidgetView({model: item});
    this.$el.append(this.View.render().el);
},


});
```

Child View:

```
var app = app || {};

app.WidgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
className                               : 'widget six columns',
widgetTemplate                          : $('#widgetTemplate').html(),

initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;
    this.model = options.model;

},

render: function() {
    var modelIndexOfCollection = this.model.collection.indexOf(this.model);

    if (!indexOfCollection & 1 === 1) {
        $('.widgets').append('<div class="widgets-row"></div>');
        this.setElement($('.widgets-row').last());
    } else {
        this.setElement($('.widgets-row').last());
    }
        this.$el.append(_.template(this.widgetTemplate)(this.model.toJSON()))   

    return this;

},

});
```

I want my HTML to look like this:

```
<div class="widgets">
    <div class="widgets-row">
        <div class="widget six columns"></div>
        <div class="widget six columns"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="widgets-row">
        <div class="widget six columns"></div>
        <div class="widget six columns"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="widgets-row">
        <div class="widget six columns"></div>
        <div class="widget six columns"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in pseudo code:

if my model is at a even postition in my collection i want to create a new div and append this and the next view to the new div.

Thanks

Parent:

```
var app = app || {};

app.WidgetsView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('.widgets'),

initialize: function(options) {
    self = this;
    this.collection = options.collection;
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
            this.renderViews(item)

    }, this);
},

renderViews: function(item) {
    this.View = new app.WidgetView({model: item});
    this.$el.append(this.View.render());
},


});
```

Child:

```
var app = app || {};

app.WidgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
className                               : 'widget six columns',
widgetTemplate                          : $('#widgetTemplate').html(),

initialize: function(options) {
    var self = this;
    this.model = options.model;

},

render: function() {
    var indexOfCollection = this.parentEl.collection.indexOf(this.model);
    if (this.isEven(indexOfCollection)) {
        $('.widgets').append('<div class="widgets-row row"></div>');
    }

    ($('.widgets-row').last()).append(this.$el.append(_.template(this.widgetTemplate)(this.model.toJSON())))    


    return this;

},

isEven: function(value) {
    if (value%2 == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
},

});
```

Comment: have found a solution and revised the question

Comment: If you solved it, post your solution as an answer (you can answer your own questions on SO). That's better than editing your question.